# Error during npm install in Angular 6 (existing project) && npm ERR! code 128

Tags: node.js, npm, angular6, file-permissions, node-modules

Actually, I am raising this question after trying all possibilities and previous questions answers. but, I don't find any clue. I think that because my problem is slightly different from those problems.

> What I did is..!

In my local system, I mistakenly Ran the following command to my entire angular project

```
Chown -R root myproject
```

and after this command, I commit the code and pushed it to the git

> What happened is..!

I pulled my code in Linux server and I ran the following command to install the new packages what I used newly in the local system

```
npm install
```

It causes the following error in Linux server
[image: Error]

> Problem is..!

I can't install node_modules due to the above error and not be able to make a production build

So, if u have clues please help me..!

Thanks in Advance :-):-)

Comment: did you try `sudo nmp install`?

Comment: Yeah..! tried, but not working it gives the same error @lagerone

Comment: but why it's return **sudo: npm: command not found** (when i trying **sudo npm install**). but **npm install** is worked and produce the problem which i asked above @lagerone

Comment: why dont you change the ownership instead? `sudo chown userName -R folderName`